# When i open an image the brushes are not there?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, brush

I was going to try to do the line art of one of my drawings on adobe illustrator, but when i open the file the brushes are not there. There's only the basic brush and i can't reduce its size. I've tried to open the image in various formats, but it didn't work. How can i solve this?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots and show us what you see. This makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Comment: --- and have you tried to open the panel by going window - > brushes?

Answer (score 0):

I would try opening up some of the default brushes in Illustration. View the image below as a reference. To access the menu, click the menu icon in the top-right corner of the brush palette. You open the brush palette by going to window > brushes.

Also, if you need to change the size, double-click on the brush icon in the tool palette.

[image: Location of Default Brushes]